# A generic function to set variables

Tags: python

I have recently got into python programming and I would like to declare a number of parameter variables within a python file that can be changed from a generic function callback from other python files. This strategy works well with C/C++, but it is not working with python.

For example: Let's say, the setter function is in `setter.py`

```
def set_param(param, val):
    globals()[param] = val
```

and in `var.py`, declared these variables:

```
pineapple = 3

class Param:
   apple = 1,
   banana = 2
```

If I try to set params like this:

```
set_param(Param.apple, 99)
set_param(pineapple, 100)
print(Param.apple)
print(pineapple)
```

This prints the following:

```
>> 1
>> 3
```

However, I would expect to see `99` and `100`. The setter does not change the static value of the variables.

This only works if I create setter functions for each param such as:

```
def set_apple(val):
    Param.apple = val
```

However, I don't prefer this method because I have a lot of parameter variables, and creating a setter function for each variable is tedious. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. Maybe it isn't, but I think it would be helpful if you outline the actual task you're trying to accomplish (preferably with a [mre]), as that will help answerers point out a potentially better solution.

Comment: What is the point of `get_param`?

Comment: `set_param(pineapple, 100)` is *completely indistinguishable* from `set_param(3, 100)` - functions receive values, NOT variables.

Comment: `globals()[param] = val` **don't do this**.

Comment: @jasonharper what is the pythonic way to set a list of variables?

Comment: @Sedmaister the pythonic way is not to dynamically create/set variables at all (and this is really just best practice when it comes to most programming languages). Use some sort of data structure or object. E.g. your `Param` object. Then jsut work with that object *directly*

Comment: `globlas()[param] = val` isn't setting a list of anything.

Comment: note, to dynamicaly modify the namespace of an object, use `setattr`/`getattr`, so `setattr(Param, name, value)`

Comment: Use a dict, or some other mutable object, instead of `globals()`.

Comment: Since you use `globals()`, you can only set global variables with that function, not object attributes. And the first argument has to be a string that names the variable, not the variable itself.

Comment: If you have the variable itself, why do you need a function? Just write `Param.apple = 99`

Comment: @j1-lee okay how would you set a varibale from another file?

Answer (score 3):

```
def set_param(param, name, val):
    if isinstance(param, dict):
        param[name] = val
    else:
        setattr(param, name, val)

pineapple = 3

class Param:
   apple = 1
   banana = 2

set_param(Param, "apple", 99)
set_param(globals(), "pineapple", 100)
print(Param.apple)
print(pineapple)
```

Comment: What if you actually want to set an attribute of a dictionary?

Comment: edited for the 3rd time

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the solution I was looking for